Passing output variable, known only at runtime, from job1 to template job2 in an AzureDevOps pipeline
I have an azure devops pipeline that has a job template.
I need to pass a variable from a previous job into the job template.
Within a job you can export a variable:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar1]test"
Across jobs you can set a flag, and import it inside variables in the next job:
    variables:
      var1: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar2;isOutput=true]test2"
However, when using a template this does not work, since you cannot pass a variable block to the template
Is there a simple way to pass an output variable (that is only known at run time) from job1 to job2 when job2 is a template?


Full example:

primary pipeline:

# ################################################################
# Update the network packages

# Push new network JSON to Topdesk
# Triggers whenever connectivityJSON is updated in main branch
# ################################################################

name: testing-passing-vars

trigger: none

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    # set a variable
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar1]test"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar2;isoutput=true]test2"
      name: setvars
      displayName: 'set vars'

    - script: |
        echo "within a job local var is available"
        echo runtimevar1: $(runtimevar1) # this works
        echo runtimevar2: $(runtimevar2) # this does not work
      displayName: echovars

  - job: job2
    dependsOn: job1
    variables:
      var2: "$[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]"
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - script: |
        echo "between jobs only the explicitely exported var is available and using the dependencies keyword in variable block op job"
        # echo runtimevar1: $(runtimevar1) # this will not work
        echo "var2: $(var2)" # this works
      displayName: echovars

  # this does not work
  - template: ./templates/jobs/test-job.yaml
    parameters:
      var1: "$[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]"
      var2: "empty"
      dependson: job1
   
  # # this is not allowed
  # - template: ./templates/jobs/test-job-variables-template.yaml
  #   variables:
  #     var2: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]
  #   parameters:
  #     var1: $(var2)
  #     var2: "empty"



template inside "templates/jobs/test-job.yaml"

parameters:
  - name: var1
    type: string

  - name: var2
    type: string

  - name: dependson
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: testjob
    displayName: testjob-template1
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependson }}
    variables:
      - name: localvar1
        value: "localvar"
      - name: remotevar
        value: "$[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]"

    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - script: |
        echo param1 var1 ${{ parameters.var1 }}
        echo param2 var2 ${{ parameters.var2 }}
        echo local var ${{ variables.localvar1 }}
        echo remote var ${{ variables.remotevar }}
      displayName: 'echo vars'


You can't pass output variables via parameters. Parameters need to be given in advance, can't be the runtime produced.
But you can define the variable in template jobs using $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ] as in your sample code, and then use it echo remote var $(remotevar) instead of ${{ variables.remotevar }}

I think you are following the right approach, but some errors occurred when using variables

Here is your sample code with some minor modifications.
main.yml
stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    # set a variable
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar1]test"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar2;isoutput=true]test2"
      name: setvars
      displayName: 'set vars'

    - script: |
        echo runtimevar1: $(runtimevar1)
        echo runtimevar2: $(setvars.runtimevar2)
      displayName: echovars

  - job: job2
    dependsOn: job1
    variables:
      var2: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "var2: $(var2)"
      displayName: echovars

  # this does not work
  - template: ./test-job.yaml
    parameters:
      var1: "hello world"

test-job.yml
parameters:
- name: var1
  type: string

jobs:
- job: testjob
  displayName: testjob-template1
  dependsOn: job1
  variables:
  - name: remotevar
    value: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]

  steps:
  # Get the Azure credentials for this environment
  - script: |
      echo param1 var1 ${{ parameters.var1 }}
      echo remote var $(remotevar)
    displayName: 'echo vars'


Please note the relative path of my file


I was hoping to avoid the hard dependency by hardcoding the job and step name in the template. But it seems there is no way around it

There may be a very funny and in-elegant way to avoid hard code. as above value using 'value: $[ dependencies.${{parameters.jobName}}.outputs['${{parameters.stepName}}.${{parameters.variableName}}'] ]'
I have not test it. it seems ugly.

To use the output variable in the downstream task from the same job, we should reference the step name by $(setvars.runtimevar2) rather than $(runtimevar2);
To use the output variables generated during runtime, we should not use compile time syntax in the script; in addition, we can define new variables in the template job with the parameter values that are passed in and reference new variables in the script using macro syntax. Here is the sample for your reference.
Primary YAML pipeline
name: testing-passing-vars

trigger: none

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    # set a variable
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar1]test"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runtimevar2;isoutput=true]test2"
      name: setvars
      displayName: 'set vars'

    - script: |
        echo "within a job local var is available"
        echo runtimevar1: $(runtimevar1) # this works
        echo runtimevar2: $(runtimevar2) # this does not work as it is not referencing the step name of the output variable
        echo setvars.runtimevar2 : $(setvars.runtimevar2) # this works
      displayName: echovars

  - job: job2
    dependsOn: job1
    variables:
      var2: "$[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]"
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - script: |
        echo "between jobs only the explicitely exported var is available and using the dependencies keyword in variable block op job"
        # echo runtimevar1: $(runtimevar1) # this will not work
        echo "var2: $(var2)" # this works
      displayName: echovars

  # this does not work
  - template: ../templates/jobs/test-job.yaml
    parameters:
      var1: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]
      var2: empty
      dependson: job1

Template YAML pipeline
parameters:
  - name: var1
    type: string

  - name: var2
    type: string

  - name: dependson
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: testjob
    displayName: testjob-template1
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependson }}
    variables:
      - name: localvar1
        value: "localvar"
      - name: remotevar
        value: "$[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvars.runtimevar2'] ]"
      - name: newVar1
        value: ${{ parameters.var1 }}
      - name: newVar2
        value: ${{ parameters.var2 }}

    steps:
    - checkout: self

    # Get the Azure credentials for this environment
    - script: |
        echo "{{local var}} ${{ variables.localvar1 }}" # this works as the value for variables.localvar1 exits in the YAML definition during pipeline compiling before runtime
        echo "{{remote var}} ${{ variables.remotevar }}" # this doesn't work as there is no value for variables.remotevar in compile time
        echo "(remote var) $(remotevar)" # this works
        echo "newVar1 $(newvar1)"
        echo "newVar2 $(newvar2)"
      displayName: 'echo vars'



See more details in the document to Understand variable syntax and Set variables in scripts
